# Error en php utilizando el MVC con metodos CRUD

Tags: php, mvc, crud

estoy tocando el tema del MVC con CRUD  a través de php. Cuando voy a mostrar los datos me aparece el error

> Missing argument 1 for Libros::__construct(), called in
>   C:\Xampp\htdocs\Proyecto MVC\Views\Libro\cargar.phtml on line 8 and
>   defined in C:\Xampp\htdocs\Proyecto MVC\Models\Libro.php on line 12.

La idea es hacer dos controladores, para a través de ellos controlar las distintas accciones.

El código es

cargar.phtml

```
    <?php
        //incluye la clase Libro y CrudLibro            
        require_once('Models/Libro.php');
        require_once('Controllers/LibroController.php');

        $libro= new Libros();
        $crud= new LibroController();
        //obtiene todos los libros con el método mostrar de la clase crud
        $listaLibros=$Libros->CargarDatos();
        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Mostrar Libros</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border=1>
                <head>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>Autor</td>
                    <td>Edicion</td>

                </head>
                <body>
                    <?php foreach ($listaLibros as $Libro) {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $libro->getautor() ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $libro->gettitulo() ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $libro->getId()?> </td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php }?>
                </body>
            </table>
            <a href="index.php">Volver</a>
        </body>
        </html>
```

La clase Models/libro.php

```
<?php 
class Libros {

    private $id;
    private $titulo;
    private $autor;


    /// etc

    //Contructor de la clase Persona
    public function __construct($id, $titulo, $autor) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->titulo = $titulo;
        $this->autor = $autor;


        /// etc
    }

    //Getter y Setters
    public function setId($id)          {    $this->id = $id;           }
    public function getId()             {    return $this‐>id;          } 
    public function setautor($autor)  {    $this->autor = $autor;   }
    public function getautor()         {    return $this‐>autor;      } 
    public function settitulo()         {    $this->titulo = $titulo;   }   
    public function gettitulo()         {    return $this‐>titulo;     



    /// ...

    /// Métodos CRUD    
   // public function Seleccionar($condicion) {       /* implementación del método Seleccionar */     } 
    function CargarDatos($row)       {       /* implementación del método CargarDatos */  

            include "includes/conexionBD.php";
            $listaLibros=[];
            $select=$db->query('SELECT * FROM libros');

            foreach($select->fetchAll() as $libro){
                $myLibro= new Libros();
                $myLibro->setId($libro['id']);
                $myLibro->setautor($libro['autor']);
                $myLibro->settitulo($libro['titulo']);


                $listaLibros[]=$myLibro;
            }
            return $listaLibros;
        }   } 
    public function Almacenar()             {       /* implementación del método Almacenar */       } 
    public function Actualizar()            {       /* implementación del método Actualizar */      } 
    public function Eliminar()              {       /* implementación del método Eliminar */        } 

    /// Otros métodos útiles relacionados con la clase Persona
    /// ....
}

?>
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar la clase `Models/Libro.php`?

Comment: La he añadido a la pregunta

Comment: Como imaginaba, en el `__construct($id, $titulo, $autor)` de la clase `Libros` declaras 3 argumentos necesarios pero, cuando instancias la clase `$libro= new Libros()` no le pasas ningún parametro.

Answer (score 0):

la clase `libros` requiere tres parametros segun su definicion. Por lo tanto, te da error en la linea  `$libro= new Libros();`

Es muy posible que esta pagina que estas definiendo sea tu "list" de libros. Por lo tanto, vas a tener que modificar el constructor de tu clase.

Por otra parte, los metodos CRUD deben estar en otra clase a la que se suele llamar CONTROLLER. Esta es la que va a llamar a la bbdd, y generar ciertos objetos de tipo LIBRO. Tu parte de codigo de presentacion deberá recibir ese listado de entidades libro, y presentarlas en consecuencia.

Analiza mas detenidamente lo que es un MVC.

Comment: me sigue dando error en el $listaLibros=$Libros->CargarDatos();

Comment: Cierto. Porque defines un objeto `libro` y llamas a `libros->cargardatos`. Revisa y refactorización tu codigo, esos métodos deben estar en un controller

Comment: La clase Libros es la que contiene el método cargardatos. Necesariamente tendría que crear el controller?

Comment: seria lo suyo, estructurarlo de forma general, como se hace en los frameworks actuales. Las acciones estarian en los controladores.